# I have changed to PropTypes to "prop-types" but still get Error evaluating React.PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, prototype, prototypejs

Environment:

OS: Linux 5.3
Node: 12.16.1
Yarn: 1.21.1
npm: 6.13.4
Watchman: 4.9.0
Xcode: N/A
Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312

```
Packages: (wanted => installed)
react: ^16.3.0-alpha.0 => 16.13.0
react-native: 0.55.0 => 0.55.0
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.0",
    "react-native": "0.55.0",
    "react-native-parabolic": "~1.1.1",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "~0.7.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "~1.5.4",
    "react-native-tab-navigator": "~0.3.3"
  }
```

```
export default class DefaultTabBar extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super()
  }

  static propTypes = {
    goToPage: PropTypes.func,
    activeTab: PropTypes.number,
    tabs: PropTypes.array,
    backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
    activeTextColor: PropTypes.string,
    inactiveTextColor: PropTypes.string,
    textStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
    tabStyle: View.propTypes.style,
    renderTab: PropTypes.func,
    underlineStyle: View.propTypes.style,
  };
```

imgae:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQYgY.jpg

How can i fix it?

Comment: Could you show the import for `PropTypes` ? I guess you import it wrong

Comment: here: import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

Comment: Do you have any ideal? @108

Comment: The import correct. Huh, could you check in `node_modules` folder that package `props-types` exist ? If you still not able to fix it, you can try to reproduce the issue in online IDE like Codesanbox and post project URL in here

Comment: @108 Can I send you github repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question not clear. But i think this is your problem:

`View.propTypes` **deprecated.**

-> Change to use `ViewPropTypes` instead.

```
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';
...

underlineStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
```

Comment: What about Text.propTypes.style?

Comment: @vuongdingo Text.propTypes.style still be supported

Comment: How can I check error if it doen;t show anything. The white screen appear after I had chanced

Comment: Can I ask you one question, what is the purpose of Proptypes ? I'm test a project which I have downloaded in Github and I'm trying to upgrade it to the newer version of ReactNative. So I don't know what exacly purpose of the snippet above.

Comment: PropTypes as its name, is the type checker for react components props